# Sorting a class member with a custom predicate

Tags: c++

I have a scenario that looks like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

// a "heavy" struct with lots of members
struct B {
  int key;
  // other members  
} 

class A {
  vector<B> bs;
}
```

I want to sort the bs by their keys. Now, a way I've done this in the past to avoid swapping Bs (since they're rather heavy), is to define a vector of indices and sort the indices instead. This works if bs is not a class member.

e.g.

```
vector<B> bs;
vector<size_t> indices;

bool pred(size_t i, size_t j) { return bs[i] < bs[j]; }

indices.resize(bs.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < bs.size(); i++) indices[i] = i;
std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), pred);
```

However, when bs is a class member, this "technique" fails because the predicate can only take two parameters. In particular, there's no way of passing "this".

I can see three different ways to solve this problem:

- Don't bother with the indices. Just overload operator `<` to handle instances of B. This whole indices thing is just premature optimization :-)
- Have a global pointer to `bs`, set it before calling `sort`, and use it in `pred`.
- **Use closures**. This would be pretty cool, except I'm not using C++11.

Is there any other way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `b` is in `class A` and is accessible through a member function called `get`, you can write a functor like this:

```
struct Comparator
{
  Compartor(A& a): m_a(a){}
  bool operator()(int i, int j) const
  {
    return m_a.get(i) < m_a.get(j);
  }

 A& m_a;
};
```

And use it like this:

```
A a;
std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), Comparator(a));
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't think about using a functor. Thanks!

Comment: Even better, I can pass a `const B&` to `Comparator`'s constructor. In this way I don't need to provide a getter method for `bs`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can write a lightweight swap for `B` then the problem doesn't really exist: `sort` will use your lightweight swap.

If that's not an option you could store (smart) pointers to your class in the vector and sort the pointers.

Or make your class use the pimpl idiom and then swap because almost free.

Definitely don't use a global pointer, because sometime someone will want to make this code threadsafe and that global container used for sorting will be a giant thorn in any attempt to multi-thread sorting of these objects.

Comment: Implementing a lightweight swap is an interesting idea, even though it wouldn't apply here. I remember seeing the Cheshire Cat idiom at school, but did not remember it :)